# Java memory leak validation

Tags: java, memory, allocation, profiler

When I profile my application with NetBeans 8.2 Profiler, every time I force a garbage collection, the number of surviving generations rises.

[image: Garbage Collection]

However, when I track the live instances, I see that their generation ages are **stable** (increasing till a certain point, then decreasing).

[image: Memory Usage]

When I simply run the app, it is noticeable that its' memory usage rises over time in TaskManager.

I can't quite figure out how this is possible and what all of this means.

Comment: You can't force a garbage collection. Only suggest that it should run...

Comment: You might also want to log GC collections, just to verify that a GC is actually happening, and what kind of GC.

Comment: Here's a GC tunning guide but it also talks about what GC logging options are available. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/index.html